# How to return multiple values in return while using Redux Dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, redux

How to return multiple value while redux dispatch(reducerName({type:'SET_DATA', here many return is it possible}) ?

```
.then(data => {
//react-redux method - it doesn't allow 
      dispatch(table({
        type: 'SET_DATA',
        receipts: (data.Items[0].receipts),
        expenditures: (data.Items[0].expenditures),
        bank:  (data.Items[0].bank),
        balance: data.Items[0].receipts-data.Items[0].expenditures
      }))
//react method - but it allows
      this.setState({
        receipts: (data.Items[0].receipts),
        expenditures: (data.Items[0].expenditures),
        bank:  (data.Items[0].bank),
        balance: data.Items[0].receipts-data.Items[0].expenditures
      })
```

In reducer when is use

```
case 'SET_DATA':
   return ( 
      state.receipts = action.payload
      state.expenditures = same
```

can i return multiple value in here

Comment: You can use the object types for those problems, and then you call the store within objects and parsed your value.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> //react-redux method - it doesn't allow 
>       dispatch(table({
>         type: 'SET_DATA',
>         receipts: (data.Items[0].receipts),
>         expenditures: (data.Items[0].expenditures),
>         bank:  (data.Items[0].bank),
>         balance: data.Items[0].receipts-data.Items[0].expenditures
>       }))
> ```

It does allow it. What makes you think that it doesn't?

All you need to do is in your reducer, get the correct values from action like this:

```
case 'SET_DATA':
   // return ( 
      // state.receipts = action.payload
      // state.expenditures = same
   // instead of above, use below
   return {
      ...state,
      recipients: action.recipients,
      expenditures: action.expenditures,
      // ...
   };
```

Comment: i have solved it using  `dispatch(table({type: 'SET_RECEIPTS', payload: (data.Items[0].receipts)}))
      dispatch(table({type: 'SET_EXPEND', payload: (data.Items[0].expenditures)}))` in the return `case 'SET_BANK':
            return state.bank = action.payload
        case 'SET_RECEIPTS':
            return state.receipts = action.receipts` does it look same to your or length

Comment: that could work too, but that requires multiple actions unnecessarily, unless you need to call them in another place again.